# At which point during preprocessing stage is __LINE__ expanded?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have a function in a header file:

```
template <int line>
inline void log() {}
```

And then I try this trick to make using it easier:

`#define LOG_LINE log<__LINE__>()`

And then in a .cpp file I do:

```
void main()
{
    LOG_LINE;
}
```

And it seems that it works the way I'd like it to. I get the line from .cpp file, not the line at which `LOG_LINE` is declared in .h file. But I don't understand how it works. Does C++ perfrom double-pass preprocessing, leaving special macros like `__LINE__` for second pass? Is this portable (standard) behavior? Should I expect this to work with all major C++ compilers? So far I've only tried MSVC.

Comment: (Aside: `void main` is invalid.)

Comment: Yes, the return type must be int. The args can be whatever, or none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is portable, standard behaviour. Yes you can depend on it.

The reason is that the #define command simply **stores** the tokens that constitute the expansion text without interpreting it or expanding it at all. Because they are tokens, white space and comments are not stored.

Then when the macro name is **used** in the program text, it is replaced by the expansion text (and any arguments as needed). Then any tokens in the substituted text are scanned and replaced, and so on (except there is no recursive replacement).

In your case it takes two expansions to get to the underlying line number.

See N3797 16.3. It's relatively readable, for a standards document. There are examples quite close to what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

One should distinguish between the number of passes through the entire input, which is what terms like *single-pass* normally refer to, and handling of nested expansions. The preprocessor normally expands all macros in a single pass through the file, but it correctly expands the expanded forms, until there is nothing left to expand.

That is, `LOG_LINE` gets expanded to `log<__LINE__>()`, where `__LINE__` again gets expanded to `3`, producing the final expansion `log<3>()` — all in a single pass through the compilation unit.

Answer (score 2):

This does not need double pass preprocessing. This is about the order of expansion of nested macros (well, in a sense, an expression is expanded in as many *passes* as needed to expand all the nested macros). A quote from an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202147/is-there-a-way-to-control-macro-expansion-order):

> All arguments which don't appear after the # operator or either side of a ## are fully macro expanded when they are replaced, not before the function-like macro is expanded.